# Javascript :What does element.attribute return ? How to use it in an URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**If we have a image tag with attributes source and alternate text**

Say for example

```
<img src="www.abc.com" alt="hi" / >
```

now `img.alt` will return us a string `"hi"`, and `img.src` will return us a string `"www.abc.com"`. Now if I want to add a background image to my any element using Javascript code

```
element.style.backgroundImage="url("www.abc.com")";
```

What  should i use to write in place of  `url("www.abc.com")`, I am having doubt whether to use `url(img.src)` or `url(' + img.src + ' )` or `url(" '+ img.src +' ")` Please help me I am confused.

Comment: As long as the url doesn't contain any quotes, you don't need string delimiters around urls in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `element.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";`

Comment: *If* you add quotes, don't forget to escape them in the url.